# datatable ajax xml display with master-detail relationship

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, datatables

Through that jQ bootstrap 4 datatable grid (datatable.net) I want for tabular display the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persns> 
  <prsn> 
  <fname>Smith</fname>  <!-- first name-->
  <lname>Milton</lname> <!-- last name --> 
  <age>44</age> 
  <e-mail>smilt@gmail.com</e-mail> 
  <phnmbr>3568236712</phnmbr>
  <addrss>5th summer st, mntb</addrss>
  <city>Portland</city>
 </prsn>
 <prsn> 
  <fname>Ken</fname> 
  <lname>Jackson</lname> 
  <age>37</age>
  <e-mail>ken.jackson@yahoo.com</e-mail> 
  <phnmbr>2638762076</phnmbr> 
  <addrss>19th Penfield ave, brtcl</addrss>
  <city>Kelowna</city>
 </prsn>
 <prsn> 
  <fname>Susan</fname>
  <lname>Arkland</lname> 
  <age>48</age>
  <e-mail>s.arklnd@hotmail.com</e-mail>
  <phnmbr>50834219704</phnmbr>
  <addrss>34th Mansfield st, sgtp</addrss>
  <city>Raleigh</city>
 </prsn>
 <prsn>
  <fname>Patsy</fname> 
  <lname>Brighton</lname>
  <age>38</age>
  <e-mail>patsy.brghton@gmail.com</e-mail> 
  <phnmbr>814522096358</phnmbr> 
  <addrss>12th Peel st, pnslv</addrss>
  <city>Philadelphia</city>
 </prsn>
 <prsn>
  <fname>John</fname>
  <lname>Torg</lname>
  <age>54</age>
  <e-mail>john.torg@tzeus.com</e-mail> 
  <phnmbr>042197327784</phnmbr>
  <addrss>27th north st, cnda</addrss>
  <city>Penticton</city>
</prsn>
```

but with master-detail functionality as it is shown over the following fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/nnb97rh9/3/

Only that up to that fiddle there is .json data ! (and I need for .xml display)
The corresponding (almost functional) .js (through the master table I only want to display the following table headers:
 fname, lname, age, city while the rest would be hidden; they'll only be displayed as related child table lines) is as follows:

```
$(function(){
 var prstbl = $("#prsns").dataTable(columns: [{"class":'details-control', 
"orderable":false, "data":null, "defaultContent":''},
          {dtaTbl:"fname"},
          {dtaTbl:"lname"},
          {dtaTbl:"age"},
          {dtaTbl:"city"},
          {dtaTbl:"e-mail", "visible":false},
          {dtaTbl:"phnmbr", "visible":false},
          {dtaTbl:"addrss", "visible":false}
         ]}),
 oTable = $('#prsne').DataTable()

function format(d)
{ 
  return '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding- 
  left:40px">'
+ '<tr>' + '<td>e-mail addrss</td>'
+ '<td>' + d.email + '</td>' + '</tr>'
+ '<tr>' + '<td>phn nmber</td>'
+ '<td>' + d.phnmbr + '</td>' + '</tr>'
+ '<tr>' + '<td>address</td>'
+ '<td>' + d.addrss + '</td>' + '</tr>'
+ '</table>'
}

$.ajax({type:"GET", url:"persns.xml", dataType:"xml", success:
function(xml)
{
var prsns = $(xml).find("prsn")
prsns.each(function(idx, prs)
        {
         var prs = $(prs), dtaTbl = [] 
         prs.children().each(function(j,chdnd)
             {
              dtaTbl.push($(chdnd).text())  
             })
         prstbl.fnAddData(dtaTbl)
      })
 }
})

$('#prsns tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function()
        {
         var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
             row = oTable.row(tr) 
         if(row.child.isShown()) // if the row is already expanded, 
    collapse it
         {
          row.child.hide()
          tr.removeClass('shown')
         }
         else // if collapsed row, expandit it 
         {
          row.child(format(row.data())).show()
          tr.addClass('shown')
      }
   })
 })
```

The relevant .html part is like this:

```
<body>
 <h5>Master-detail persons display</h5>
  <table id="prsns" border="1" class="table display" width="60%">
  <thead><tr><th></th><th>frst nme</th><th>name</th><th>age</th> 
   <th>city</th> <th>e-mail addrss</th></tr></thead> 
  <tbody></tbody>
 </table>
</body>
```

And there is also a small .css file like this:

td.details-control
{
background:url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
cursor: pointer;
}

tr.shown td.details-control
{ background:url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}

I repeat, all the displaying I need to be done regarding this .xml file and not .json or only .html !
I know how to do it with .json table.
 So you guys please help me with this issue.
 Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code, too much to describe. Below is the corrected code.

Please note I am using jsFiddle mechanism to retrieve XML file, replace with your own.

```
(function () {
   function format(d) {
      return '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left: 40 px ">' +
         '<tr>' + '<td>e-mail addrss</td>' +
         '<td>' + d['e-mail'] + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
         '<tr>' + '<td>phn nmber</td>' +
         '<td>' + d['phnmbr'] + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
         '<tr>' + '<td>address</td>' +
         '<td>' + d['addrss'] + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
         '</table>';
   }

   var prstbl = $("#prsns").DataTable({
      columns: [
         {
            "class": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": ''
         },
         {
            data: "fname"
         },
         {
            data: "lname"
         },
         {
            data: "age"
         },
         {
            data: "city"
         },
         {
            data: "e-mail",
            "visible": false
         },
         {
            data: "phnmbr",
            "visible": false
         },
         {
            data: "addrss",
            "visible": false
         }
      ]
   });

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/echo/xml",
      data: {
            xml: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><persns>'
            + '<prsn><fname>Smith</fname><lname>Milton</lname><age>44</age><e-mail>smilt@gmail.com</e-mail><phnmbr>3568236712</phnmbr><addrss>5th summer st, mntb</addrss><city>Portland</city></prsn>'
            + '<prsn><fname>Ken</fname><lname>Jackson</lname><age>37</age><e-mail>ken.jackson@yahoo.com</e-mail><phnmbr>2638762076</phnmbr><addrss>19th Penfield ave, brtcl</addrss><city>Kelowna</city></prsn>'
            + '<prsn><fname>Susan</fname><lname>Arkland</lname><age>48</age><e-mail>s.arklnd@hotmail.com</e-mail><phnmbr>50834219704</phnmbr><addrss>34th Mansfield st, sgtp</addrss><city>Raleigh</city></prsn>'
            + '<prsn><fname>Patsy</fname><lname>Brighton</lname><age>38</age><e-mail>patsy.brghton@gmail.com</e-mail><phnmbr>814522096358</phnmbr><addrss>12th Peel st, pnslv</addrss><city>Philadelphia</city></prsn>'
            + '<prsn><fname>John</fname><lname>Torg</lname><age>54</age><e-mail>john.torg@tzeus.com</e-mail><phnmbr>042197327784</phnmbr><addrss>27th north st, cnda</addrss><city>Penticton</city></prsn>'
        + '</persns>',
      },
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function (xml) {
         var prsns = $(xml).find("prsn");
         prsns.each(function (idx, prs) {
            var rowData = [];
            $(prs).children().each(function (j, chdnd) {
               rowData[$(chdnd).get(0).tagName] = $(chdnd).text();
            });
                prstbl.row.add(rowData);
        });

        prstbl.draw();       
      }
   });

    $('#prsns tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var row = prstbl.row(tr);

      // if the row is already expanded, collapse it
      if (row.child.isShown())  {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        // if collapsed row, expand it             
      } else {
         row.child(format(row.data())).show();
         tr.addClass('shown');
      }
   });
})();
```

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/h5ecfm9z/1/) for code and demonstration.